# find -iname not working in script

Tags: bash, find

Following find command.

```
find Work/Linux4/test/test/test_goal/spyglass_reports/clock-reset/Ac_coherency06/ -iname "Ac_coherency*.csv"
```

is working fine when run on shell. 
But in perl script it return nothing.

```
#!/bin/bash

REPORT_DIR=$1
FIND_CMD=$2

echo "@@";
echo $REPORT_DIR ;
echo $FIND_CMD ;

LIST_OF_CSV=$(find $REPORT_DIR $FIND_CMD)
echo $LIST_OF_CSV

if [ "X" == "X${LIST_OF_CSV}" ]; then
    echo "No files Found for : '$FIND_CMD' in directory "; 
    echo " '$REPORT_DIR' " | sed -e 's;Work/.*/test_reports;Work/PLATFORM/test_reports;g';
    echo;
    exit 0;
fi
```

Output of script:

```
@@
Work/$PLATFORM_SPECIES/test_reports/clock-reset/Ac_coherency06 -iname "Ac_coherency06*.csv"

No files Found for : '-iname "Ac_coherency06*.csv"' in directory     'Work/PLATFORM/test_reports/clock-reset/Ac_coherency06'
```

Comment: You're using a relative path, are you running the script from a good location?  Also, try running with `set -x` to see if your command is really expanding the variables the way you want--storing code in variables frequently doesn't work the way people expect (see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: It seems you're passing one argument to your script, enclosed in single quotes, something like `./myscript 'Work/$PLATFORM_SPECIES/test_reports/clock-reset/Ac_coherency06 -iname "Ac_coherency06*.csv"'`. This can't work: after word splitting (and hopefully there are no files that match your glob), `find` will see the three arguments `Work/$PLATFORM_SPECIES/test_reports/clock-reset/Ac_coherency06`, `-iname` and `"Ac_coherency06*.csv"` with quotes: the directory given (likely) doesn't exist, and even if it existed, there are no files matching because of the quotes.

Comment: Well, in fact you're probably passing two arguments as `./myscript 'Work/$PLATFORM_SPECIES/test_reports/clock-reset/Ac_coherenc‌​y06' '-iname "Ac_coherency06*.csv"'` (there's a mismatch with your script and the output you give us)... but anyway this is plain wrong.

Comment: Consider running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ before asking questions here. That said, there are other things wrong as well -- your `LIST_OF_CSV`, for instance, *isn't actually an array variable*; you can't safely store arrays in string variables, because anything that could delimit two different entries in an array (a space, a newline, etc) is also potentially present as literal part of a filename.

Comment: Moreover, all-caps variable names are used for variables with meaning to the operating system or the shell itself -- see [the relevant POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html), paragraph four. Even though the spec applies to environment variables, setting a shell variable will overwrite any like-named environment variable, so the convention necessarily applies to both.

Comment: As another aside, `==` isn't actually a valid operator in [POSIX `test`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html); the only string comparison operator guaranteed by the standard is `=`, and bash supports `==` as an extension. If you want to use extensions, consider using `[[ ]]` instead of `[ ]`; that way you're explicitly using non-POSIX syntax.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a command that is running well on the shell but not on your script, the first thing I would try would be to specify Bash on the command being called, see if this works:

```
bash -c 'find Work/Linux4/test/test/test_goal/spyglass_reports/clock-reset/Ac_coherency06/ -iname "Ac_coherency*.csv"'
```

Or even better:

```
/bin/bash -c 'find Work/Linux4/test/test/test_goal/spyglass_reports/clock-reset/Ac_coherency06/ -iname "Ac_coherency*.csv"'
```

You could also store the result on a variable or other data structure as needed, and pass it later to the script, for example:

```
ResultCommand="$(bash -c 'find Work/Linux4/test/test/test_goal/spyglass_reports/clock-reset/Ac_coherency06/ -iname "Ac_coherency*.csv"')"
```

**Edit:** this answer was edited more than once to fix possible issues.

Comment: I wouldn't call this sound advice in general -- particularly using double-quotes as you are here means that in other scenarios, where code is being run that includes variable dereferences, encapsulating it in this way adds complexity and room for bugs by way of needing to distinguish correctly between quotes expanded in the outer shell and those expanded in the inner shell.

Comment: Charles, thanks for your comments. I made this with double quotes because the OP uses them on their post. The use of double quotes allows searching for file names that have a space on them, ex: `Ac_coherency  tomorrow*.csv`, and they also allow the OP to use a variable on the name file, ex: `\"$something\"`.  I suspect that the OP used double quotes because he might intend to use those capabilities at some point. Double quotes add some complexity but also add some capabilities.

Comment: The above comment actually helps to make my point: In the example of `"... \"$foo\" ..."`, the backslash-escaped quotes are only syntactic for the *inner* shell (the one started with `bash -c`); for the *outer* shell, the one that's *executing* your `bash -c` command, they have no meaning. This double-expansion can have substantial unintended consequences: If your `$foo` expands to `$(rm -rf ~)` when the outer shell runs it, then the inner shell will expand that again; whereas if the outer shell did no expansion and the inner shell expanded `$foo`, this would be safe.

Comment: Not sure I am totally following you, but if I am, this could be corrected by storing the result of the outer shell on a variable, and then passing the variable to the script, such as: `ResultCommand="$(bash -c "find Work/Linux4/test/test/test_goal/spyglass_reports/clock-reset/Ac_coherency06/ -iname \"Ac_coherency*.csv\"")"`. Do you agree? Comments?

Comment: If there's a `$foo` or `$something` in your string passed to `bash -c "..."`, then no, putting that inside a command substitution doesn't in and of itself solve the problem of double-expansion resulting in effective `eval`. You'd need to make it `bash -c '...'`, with single quotes, to be safe -- if you need to use variables, then you can do `bash -c 'echo "$1"' _ 'this is the literal value for $1'` to pass them safely out-of-band.

Comment: but, well, this is largely my point: Going the approach of using `bash -c` is adding *more* complexity, and creating more room for bugs. To the extent that it's solving anything, it's doing so in a manner that creates security exposure, and is thus a very questionable practice.

Comment: I see it now! If there's a (say) funny file path such as `/folder/strange stuff here $foo/file.csv` then `$foo` would expand in a unexpected way. You're right, that was an oversight of mine not to consider that something like that could be passed. Thanks for the comments! I updated my answer. It will still allow for specifying files with spaces in their names, but there would be no variable expansion (which was not asked by the OP, by the way). Do you still have a problem with my answer now? Comments (positive or negative) are welcome.

Comment: I agree that, as-amended to suggest single-quotes, this is no longer promoting practices that are innately insecure. That said, I'm still not certain that it adds much value; I'd tend to expect `set -x` in a parent shell to have considerably more utility in debugging unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 1):

If you're allowing a list of `find` predicates to be passed, **keep them in list form**, one argument to `find` per argument to your script. As an example implemented in this manner:

```
#!/bin/bash

# read report_dir off the command line, and shift it from arguments
report_dir=$1; shift

# generate a version of report_dir for human consumption
re='Work/.*/test_reports'
replacement='Work/PLATFORM/test_reports'
if [[ $report_dir =~ $re ]]; then
  report_dir_name=${report_dir//${BASH_REMATCH[0]}/$replacement}
else
  report_dir_name=$report_dir
fi

# read results from find -- stored NUL-delimited -- into an array
# using NUL-delimited inputs ensure that even unusual filenames work correctly
declare -a list_of_csv
while IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do
 list_of_csv+=( "$filename" )
done < <(find "$report_dir" '(' "$@" ')' -print0)

# Use the length of that array to determine whether we found contents
echo "Found ${#list_of_csv[@]} files" >&2

if (( ${#list_of_csv[@]} == 0 )); then
  echo "No files found in $report_dir_name" >&2
fi
```

Here, `shift` consumes the first argument from your list, and `"$@"` refers to all the others that remain after that point. **This means that the items you want to have passed as separate, individual arguments to `find` can (and must) be passed as separate, individual arguments to your script.**

Thus, with usage `yourscript "/path/to/report/dir" -name '*.txt'`, initially, `$1` will be `/path/to/report/dir`, `$2` will be `-name`, and `$3` will be `*.txt`. However, after `shift` is run, `$1` will be `-name`, and `$2` will be `*.txt`; and `"$@"` will refer to both of those, each passed as a separate word.

---

- For details on the use of a `while read` loop to read items off of a stream, see [BashFAQ #001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).
- For details on the syntax used for bash-native string replacement, see [BashFAQ #100](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100) or http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe
- For details on shell arrays, including `${#arrayname[@]}` to check their length or `"${arrayname[@]}"` to expand to their contents, see [BashFAQ #005](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/005).